# ActiveAdmin. always show top filters above the index table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

on index page if result of search using side filters not empty i have top filters above the index table with predefined scopes but if there is no any results, this line of filters disappears...

but i need it in all cases with correct count of search results [image: top filter]

hope question is clear enough =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to monkey patch the Scopes builder class. You can easily do this by adding an initializer file to your Rails project:

**config/initializers/activeadmin_scope_patch.rb**

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Scopes < ActiveAdmin::Component
      def build(scopes, options = {})
        scopes.each do |scope|
          build_scope(scope, options) if call_method_or_proc_on(self, scope.display_if_block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works because the default renderer checks if the result set is empty and short circuits the process if so.  By removing that check, the renderer shows all the scopes with 0 items since there are no results.

Comment: looks like the solution... can you please provide fragment of code or path to file which is overridden by monkey patch (what am i loose if i implement it). thank you!

Comment: [scopes.rb, row 23 , def build(...](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/scopes.rb)

Comment: The link above is to a version that was updated 2 months ago to do just what you're after.  The only thing you lose is the function that you're trying to avoid - hiding the scopes when the result is empty.

Comment: [scopes.rb](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/0.4.x-stable/lib/active_admin/views/components/scopes.rb) for v0.4 stabile . @Troy , you are absolutely right .

Comment: looks like there is no 'more official' way to do this... like `scope :any_scope, :hide_on_nil=>false` in activeadmin resource file. accepting this answer